# How to get day of the month?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to retrieve which day of the month it is.

Such as today is August 29,2011.

What i would like to do is just get the days number such as 29, or 30. Which ever day of the month it is.

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: A quick search came up with this.. http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/DayYearToDayMonth.shtml

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You'll want to do get a Calendar instance and get it's day of month

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

String dayOfMonthStr = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
```

You can also get DAY_OF_WEEK, DAY_OF_YEAR, DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, etc.

Comment: Is there anyway to get this as a String?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 19):

The following method would help you in finding day of any specified date :

```
public static int getDayOfMonth(Date aDate) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(aDate);
    return cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate           // Represent a date-only, without time-of-day and without time zone.
.now()              // Better to pass a `ZoneId` optional argument to `now` as shown below than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone.
.getDayOfMonth()    // Interrogate for the day of the month (1-31).
```

## java.time

The modern approach is the `LocalDate` class to represent a date-only value.

A time zone is crucial in determine the current date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
int dayOfMonth = ld.getDayOfMonth();
```

You can also get the day-of-week.

```
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek();
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, and advises migration to the java.time classes. This section left intact for history.

Using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.5 library rather than the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date and .Calendar classes.

Time zone is crucial to determining a date. Better to specify the zone rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone being assigned.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime now = DateTime.now( zone ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
int dayOfMonth = now.getDayOfMonth();
```

Or use similar code with the `LocalDate` class that has no time-of-day portion.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`GregorianCalendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), something like:

```
final Calendar now = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()
final int dayNumber = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start by reading the documentation for [Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Then you realize that Date’s methods are all deprecated and turn to [Calender](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simplified a lot in version Java 8. I have given some util methods below.

> To get the day of the month in the format of `int` for the given day, month, and year.

```java
    public static int findDay(final int month, final int day, final int year) {
        // System.out.println(LocalDate.of(year, month, day).getDayOfMonth());
        return LocalDate.of(year, month, day).getDayOfMonth();
    }
```

> To get current day of the month in the format of `int`.

```java
    public static int findDay(final int month, final int day, final int year) {
        // System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).getDayOfMonth());
        return LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).getDayOfMonth();
    }
```

> To get the day of the week in the format of `String` for the given day, month, and year.

```java
    public static String findDay(final int month, final int day, final int year) {
        // System.out.println(LocalDate.of(year, month, day).getDayOfWeek());
        return LocalDate.of(year, month, day).getDayOfWeek().toString();
    }
```

> To get current day of the week in the format of `String`.

```java
    public static String findDay(final int month, final int day, final int year) {
        // System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))..getDayOfWeek());
        return LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).getDayOfWeek().toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java 8 Update**

Java 8 introduces the following packages for time and date manipulation.

```
java.time.*;
java.time.format.*;

java.time.chono.*;    
java.time.temporal.*;
java.time.zone.*;
```

These are more organized and intuitive.

We need only top two packages for the discussion.
There are 3 top level classes - `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime` for describing Date, Time and DateTime respectively. Although, they are formatted properly in `toString()`, each class has format method which accepts `DateTimeFormatter` to format in customized way.

`DateTimeFormatter` can also be used show the date given a day. It has few

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

class DateTimeDemo{
    public static void main(String...args){
        LocalDateTime x = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(x.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL)));//Shows Day and Date.

        System.out.println(x.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE")));//Short Form
        System.out.println(x.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE")));//Long Form

    }
}
```

`ofLocalizedTime` accepts `FormatStyle` which is an enumeration in `java.time.format`

`ofPattern` accepts `String` with restricted pattern characters of restricted length. Here are the characters which can be passed into the `toPattern` method.

[image]

You can try different number of patterns to see how the output will be.

Check out more about Java 8 DateTime API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

LocalDate date = new Date();
date.lengthOfMonth()

or

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd");

DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM");

String stringDate = formatter.format(date);

String month = monthFormatter.format(date);

Answer (score 0):

You can try  the Java 8 [YearMonth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

```java
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

String dateTest = "08 29,2011";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM dd,yyyy");
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse(dateTest, formatter);
int lengthOfMonth = yearMonth.lengthOfMonth();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//This will get you the day of the month
String.valueOf((Calendar.getInstance()).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Please explain so that one could get more idea about what your code is doing.