# How to get day from a month java

Tags: java

I have a calendar picker that allows user to pick a start date and end dates.

I want to extract the day from a month, the old way to use getDay produces a wrong day from a month. Is there any other methods that I can use to get the date from a month and put it into an int type?

```
      Date date_from = HolidayForm.pickerFrom.getDate();
      Date date_to = HolidayForm.pickerTo.getDate();

      //getDay is deprecated 
      int from = date_from.getDay();
      int to = date_to.getDay();

      //so i can do to find difference. 
      int diff = to-from;
```

Comment: Use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or – even better – [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226156/how-to-get-day-of-the-month

Comment: Just a heads up, as I didn't understand initially. This is being downvoted as getDate() is deprecated, and I believe was deprecated when this post was made.

Answer (score 6):

Using [**Calendar API**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

Methods in `java.util.Date` class are mostly deprecated. you have to use `java.util.calendar` class in order to do manipulation on dates.

```
Date d = new Date(); 
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(d);
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object :

Try this :

```
Date date_from = HolidayForm.pickerFrom.getDate();
Date date_to = HolidayForm.pickerTo.getDate();

Calendar calFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
calFrom.setTime(date_from);
int from = calFrom.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

Calendar calTo = Calendar.getInstance();
calTo.setTime(date_to);
int to = calTo.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

int diff = to-from;
```

Comment: I wrote the same code as this before, doesnt work,but then i copied this code, it works. Programming is like magic.  :)) thanks