# Update only one day of the month android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have some things in my Android application that need to update once per Month.
Everything is correct but how do I set the time?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.add( ?, ?);

  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: When you ask how to set the time, are you looking to set the current date and time, or are you looking to set a variable with the date and time of the update?

Comment: I wanted to update twenty-ninth of each month. (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this question for getting the day of the month using Calendar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226156/how-to-get-day-of-the-month)

Then, figure out what month the user is currently in using

`cal.get(Calendar.MONTH_OF_YEAR)`

and set your variable to the 29th of that month.

Consider February in this implementation ;)