# How do find day number(integer) of last day in the current month

Tags: java, date

I have specific date and i want to find last day number(integer) of month. I am using following code but always return current of date.

```
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Date date = (Date) sdf.parse(year+"-"+(month<10?("0"+month):month)+"-01");


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);

    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

    Date dt = (Date) calendar.getTime(); -> dt is return current date always
```

example: my date = 2018/04/30 and i want to find 30.

I couldnt find answer at site.

Thnx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get day of the month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226156/how-to-get-day-of-the-month)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I get Mon Apr 30 00:00:00 CEST 2018. And `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` gives me 30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> have specific date and i want to find last day number(integer) of month

[`getActualMaximum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum-int-) is what you are looking for here.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(parsedDate);
cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 4):

If using Java 8 (or higher), don't use `Calendar`. If using Java 6 or 7, you might want to consider using the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). In either case, use the Java Time API.

---

#### Using Java Time

Since input is `int year` and `int month`, use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).

To find last day number of month, call [`lengthOfMonth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#lengthOfMonth--).

To get the date at the end of month, call [`atEndOfMonth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#atEndOfMonth--).

*Demo*

```
int year = 2020;
int month = 2;

int lastDay = YearMonth.of(year, month).lengthOfMonth();
System.out.println(lastDay);

LocalDate date = YearMonth.of(year, month).atEndOfMonth();
System.out.println(date);
```

*Output*

```
29
2020-02-29
```

---

#### Using Joda-Time

If you don't have Java 8, and already use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), do it this way:

*Demo*

```
int year = 2020;
int month = 2;

int lastDay = new LocalDate(year, month, 1).dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue();
System.out.println(lastDay);

LocalDate date = new LocalDate(year, month, 1).dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
System.out.println(date);
```

*Output*

```
29
2020-02-29
```

---

#### Using Calendar

If you insist on using `Calendar`, call [`getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum-int-) as also mentioned in other answers.

Since input is `int year` and `int month`, don't build and parse a string, just set `Calendar` fields directly. Note that "month" in `Calendar` is zero-based.

*Demo*

```
int year = 2020;
int month = 2;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(year, month - 1, 1);
int lastDay = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, lastDay);
Date date = calendar.getTime();

System.out.println(lastDay);
System.out.printf("%tF%n", date);
```

*Output*

```
29
2020-02-29
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use calendar for that, like this:

```
calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Or, if you have joda, which is usually better:

```
DateTime d = new DateTame(dt);
d.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue();
```

Comment: How does return the last day of month?

Comment: I used this code too. But gave me month day of current date.

Comment: @ScaryWombat that's true, I didn't notice immediately the last day requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1); 
calendar.roll(Calendar.DATE, -1); 
int lastDate=calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
```

Comment: get the first day of the month,and rollback one day

Comment: You should edit the answer and add that text, instead of leaving it as a comment. Then delete the comment.

Answer (score 1):

First, how are you getting the year to be used?

it should be simple by using Java Time LocalDate:

```
import java.time.*;
import static java.time.Month.*;
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.*;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.*;

int lastDay = LocalDate.now()   // or whatever date you want
                  .with(Month.of(yourMonth))
                  .with(lastDayOfMonth())
                  .get(DAY_OF_MONTH);

 // or, if you have year and month, and want to find the corresponding last day
int lastDay = LocalDate.of(yourYear, yourMonth, 1)
                  .with(lastDayOfMonth())
                  .get(DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: You should use `YearMonth` class. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50619041/5221149).

Comment: true, YearMonth is actually better in such case (I was writing the solution  with parsing an input date in mind... :P )

Comment: I would still prefer this way over using `Calendar` any time. `Calendar` is long outdated and poorly designed. Agree that `YearMonth` is a further (minor) improvement. +1 to both of you.

Comment: @OleV.V. Same here. For any project I have control, I only consider using Java Time (Java8+) or Joda/310-backport (Java7 or earlier).  Date is probably the only legacy class I will use.  There is simply no reason to use Calendar